# Smudge and Clean filters, smudge work, clean not

Tags: git

Smudge and Clean filters.
Smudge work, Clean is ignored.

In the attributes file
C:\Users\Riaan\.config\git\attributes

> ```
> *.cbl filter=Promote
> ```

entered these commands in Git Bash

> ```
> git config --global filter.Promote.smudge "/C/Users/Riaan/.config/git/Promote.smudge" 
> git config --global filter.Promote.clean "/C/Users/Riaan/.config/git/Promote.clean"
> ```

Promote.smudge

> ```
> #! /bin/sh -f
> sed \
> -e 's|/u/files1/|U:\\files1\\|' \
> -e 's|"SYSTEM"|"MFSYSTEM"|' \
> $1
> ```

Promote.clean

> ```
> #! /bin/sh -f 
> sed \
> -e 's|U:\\files1\\|/u/files1/|' \
> -e 's|"MFSYSTEM"|"SYSTEM"|' \
> $1
> ```

(there are more similar lines excluded for simplicity)

Purpose of both filters are mostly changing linux folder structures into windows format "/u/" into "U:\"

Cloning a repository and the smudge filter does execute. Master repository is on linux and my created repository got all the filenames in the windows format.

Linux: ASSIGN TO "/u/files1/STAFF"

Windows: ASSIGN TO "U:\files1\STAFF"

Promoting programs back to linux and the trigger is just not executed at all. What else must be set.

Note, I'm running git bash on a Windows 10 PC.

Comment: found it - eventually

In the GIT config the paths must be a mix match between windows format and linux format.

[filter "Promote"]
 clean = "C:/Users/Riaan/.config/git/Promote.clean"
 smudge = "C:/Users/Riaan/.config/git/Promote.smudge"

must use windows C:
but use linux forward slashes.

Comment: seems on the smudge, having the path with /c/ is not a problem
but the clean filter, it must be c:/